# Adding cells to a view

Tags: swift

I'm creating a weather application in order to learn Swift.
I have a a view (inside a `navigationContoller`), I want to display a 6 days forecast in the bottom half of the screen and for that I need to create cells in a stack or something.
I tried to look up how to create those cells (which needs to have temp, date, and image) but could only find things related to `UITableView` which to my limited understanding I need to create another `ViewController` for it and I have no idea on how to start.
Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: "create cells in a stack or something" Incoherent and vague. Do you want a table view or not? If you do, you are free to use one, so it's unclear what the problem is supposed to be. Is it that you've never used a table view and you want to know how? If so, the question becomes too broad; there's _lots_ of info out there about how to do it.

Comment: If needed I would gladly learn how to use it. But I really don't know what I exactly need. Hoped you guys could give me direction on what's the best way to do it and maybe a link to a good tutorial.

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is not a permissible Stack Overflow question and, as I suggested, "create cells in a stack or something" is vague. It does sound like a table view, though, so your best bet is probably to use a table view.

Answer (score 0):

> ...which to my limited understanding I need to create another ViewController for it

A `UITableView` does not have to fill the entire view, so you can add a `UITableView` to your existing `UIViewController` no problem :)

Here is an example of a storyboard with a regular view (the green one) at the top with a fixed height of 128 and below that, a `UITableView` that takes up the rest of the view.

[image]

So, to solve your problem you could:

- Create a "top view" with all the static content
- Create a `UITableView` to fill the bottom part of your view
- Drag outlets to your `UITableView`
- Populate that `UITableView` with data using the standard `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods "as usual".

As to how to implement the `UITableView`, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/) (or in general just google "UITableView Tutorial" :))

Hope that leads you in the right direction.